# Populate parent field from url kwarg in a nested serializer in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models, Catalog and Epic:

```py
class Catalog(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)


class Epic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False)
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have created CRUD viewset and serializer for Catalog, using DRF. Now I want to create CRUD viewset and serializer for Epic, to be used like `/catalogs/<int:catalog_pk>/epics/<int:pk>`. I am using DRF-nested-router:

```py
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register("catalog", CatalogViewSet)

catalog_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, "catalog", lookup="catalog")
catalog_router.register("epics", EpicsViewSet, basename="epics")

urlpatterns = router.urls + catalog_router.urls
```

And these are my viewset and serializer for Epic:

```py
class EpicsViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = EpicSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, CatalogPermissions)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Epic.objects.filter(catalog=self.kwargs["catalog_pk"])


class EpicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Epic
        fields = "__all__"
```

I am trying to run the creation endpoint like this: POST `/catalog/1/epics/` with epic data, but I get the error that `catalog` field is missing in the payload. I want this to be done automatically from URL kwargs. I want it to take the `catalog_id` from kwargs and set the catalog instance to the newly created Epic instance in the serializer.

The starightforward way would be to override the `create` function in the serializer, but I am hesitant to do that and was wondering if there is a more "pythonic" way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a simple mixin that will patch both the `get_queryset` and the `perform_create` method:

```
class FilterCreateGetMixin:
    filter_field_name = None
    filter_kwarg_name = None

    def get_filter_dict(self):
        return {self.filter_field_name: self.kwargs[self.filter_kwarg_name]}

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(**self.get_filter_dict())
        )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(**self.get_filter_dict())
```

then we can make a mixin, specifically for the category for example:

```
class CategoryFilterMixin(FilterCreateGetMixin):
    filter_field_name = 'catalog'
    filter_kwarg_name = 'catalog_pk'
```

and mix this in the viewset/API view:

```
class EpicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Epic
        exclude = ['catalog']


class EpicsViewSet(
    CategoryFilterMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    serializer_class = EpicSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, CatalogPermissions)
```

The advantage of this is that we can easily mix this into all other views where we have a `category_pk` in the path.